# Will a differentiating a single point yield 0?

Tags: calculus

For example, if a graph is just a single point plotted, will differentiating the function of the graph be 0?

Comment: What a strange question... do you know the limit definition of derivative?

Comment: The function needs to be defined in a neighbourhood of the point in order to consider even calculating the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

No because any such function has no derivative. You must first ensure that the derivative exists before you can calculate it and many functions have no derivatives anywhere. Since the definition involved limiting processes this means you must have a collection of points nearby the point where the derivative exists in order to calculate it. Since a function whose graph is a single point has no neighboring points no such derivative can exist. [Almost no functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_set) have derivatives even if we restrict ourselves to continuous functions. That being said, large classes of useful functions do have derivatives like polynomials and trig functions.